# Why don't we use momentum to quantify inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, definition, inertia

My understanding of Newton's 1st and 2nd laws have led me to believe that inertia and momentum are the same.

1st law: An external force is required to overcome an object's inertia

2nd law: Force is the rate of change of momentum, i.e an external force is required to change the momentum of an object.

These laws suggest that force is required to overcome inertia and is also required to change momentum. Wouldn't that suggest that momentum and inertia are both the same thing? And if that is true, then why is momentum not used to quantify inertia?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr Momentum and inertia are directly related, but different quantities, giving the "feeling" that they are the same quantity

Although not the same thing, they are obviously closely related. Inertia is quantified in terms of mass, while momentum is $p=mv$. Let's first analyze what would happen if we do as suggested, and treat inertia and momentum interchangeably.

Say, we replace the first law with momentum. Then, we lose the ability to show how two objects with the same mass but different velocities require the same force to change their speed. If we quantify inertia in terms of momentum, the formula for momentum gives us two different inertias we must overcome, even though in reality, they would require the same amount of force.

What's going on here is that momentum is just a related quantity, one that is directly proportional, to the inertia of an object. It is not the quantity itself, however. This is a similar question to asking if we can just represent the velocity of an object by its momentum; after all, they are directly proportional. But there is a sense in which this is wrong, for there are objects with differing velocities, but equal momentum. Likewise, there are objects which are harder to move than others (larger inertia), yet have the same momentum: it is much harder to push a slow bowling ball than a fast baseball of the same momentum. The best example that this is a problem is in the case the velocity of an object is zero: although the momentum is zero, we still have to overcome an inertia to make it move.

Answer (score 1):

A body is inertial as long as its momentum is constant for whatever time and distance; in other words over some path s. So, we need an integral; something like work which is the integral of force along the path, but these forces can add up to zero even when the body is not inertial which prompts us to take the absolute value under the integral. So, we define an `inertia integral';
$$
\xi = \int_{s} |\vec f\cdot d\vec s|
$$
So, a body is inertial over a path s, if and only if the above integral is zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't that suggest that momentum and inertia are both the same thing?

Inertia is closely related with body rest mass (in translational movement). You can have zero momentum wrt same reference frame, but different mass and hence,- different inertial properties. Similarly,- object can have zero rest mass, but non-zero momentum,- like photon which momentum can be expressed in it's [wave vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector) : $${\boldsymbol {p}}=\hbar {\boldsymbol {k}} \tag 1$$

So clearly this shows, that momentum and inertia are inter-dependent quantities, but **not the same thing**.

Secondly, it's important if we talk about translational inertia or rotational inertia. Former is related to the rest mass, while the latter - to the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia), which additionally depends on object shape and mass distribution (for example,- bigger wheels rotates longer after initial push, compared to the same mass of smaller diameter wheels). That's why for rotational movement we have completely different second Newton law :
$$ \tau=I\alpha \tag 2$$

Lastly, if we take into account theory of relativity,- namely that objects which speed approaches speed of light in vacuum are becoming more heavier, due to their mass increase (or more accurately,- due to relativistic kinetic energy increase) by a Lorentz factor :
$$ m=\gamma m_0 \tag 3 $$

This shows a-new with the invention of relativity that inertia is more related to the *total energy of the object*, and not just with it's rest mass. In the end, everything is far more complex, and you can't reduce some Physics core concepts like that.